# How to influence page number/position of float pages?

Tags: floats, page-numbering

I am using the figure environment with [p!], so that my figures get displayed on separate pages. I would like these float pages to be between text pages, e.g. if I refer to a figure on page 4 of my text I would like the float page to be page 3 or 5. However, most of my float pages are being shifted to the end of my document. Is there a way that I force the float pages to be next to the text pages that refer to them? Or set the page number of these float pages manually?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat. If the general advice doesn't help, we need to see code for a minimal document which demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Figures shifted to the end is usually the symptom of force float positions too munch. If yo do not want floats floating, maybe the best is avoid floats. Packages `caption`, `capdef` and `capt-of` allow cap­tions out­side floats. Or you can limit the  float trip  with `\clearpage`  or  \FloatBarrier from the `placeins` package, or  relax LaTeX rules as  the `\floatpagefraction`  (see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-floats.html)).

Comment: \afterpage{\clearpage} should do the trick (afterpage package).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[p!]` is equivalent to `[p]` and will allow the figure to be placed after the next page break if it meets the constraints, if it is being held to the end the most likely constraint that is failing is `\floatpagefraction` if the figure is smaller than `\floatpagefraction` then it will be held back to avoid float pages being too empty, but then if that float and the next combine to be more than the text height they can not fit either so the constraints are not achievable and all floats will get held to the end of document or `\clearpage`.

Setting something like

```
\renewcommand\floatpagefraction{.1}
```

makes it much easier to place figures in float pages.

Comment: thank you, \renewcommand\floatpagefraction{.1} did the trick for me and i didn't have to use \clearpage ! (The issue with \clearpage would have been that a text page would have to end with the end of paragraphs or else with a lot of blank space at the bottom of the page.)